# Command with simple parsing

Tags: macros

I would like to write a command `\foo` that takes a math-mode expression and renders it with some selected symbols (say denoted by `#`) printed in `\mathcal`. For example, `\foo{#X^A_B}` should expand to `\mathcal{X}^A_B`.

As a side question, it would be convenient if the command had the following behaviour. If the input consists of multiple symbols, then it is parsed as described above. However, if the input consists of only a single symbol, then
this symbol should be converted to `\mathcal` even if it is not preceded by `#`. E.g. `\foo{X}` and `\foo{#X}` should both expand to `\mathcal{X}` while `\foo{X^A}` should expand to `X^A`.

What is the simplest way to accomplish this? I do not insist on this particular syntax. Any reasonably compact syntax will do.

Comment: To be more explicit, you'd like that `\foo{X^A_B}` does `\mathcal{X}^A_B`? What characters should be subject to the transformation? And isn't it better to type `\mc{X}^A_B`?

Comment: And what should other symbols be? What's the replacement then?

Comment: @egreg, no `\foo{X^A_B}` should be just `X^A_B` since `X` was not labelled by `#`. I don't want a shortcut like `\mc{X}` since `\foo` is really a longer name that carries some meaning that I want to retain to make the code more readable.

Comment: @KarolSzumiło Please make more precise what you mean by “regardless of the presence of `#`”.

Comment: @egreg, I edited the question to clarify.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idea is to make `\foo` open a group and set a selected character as math active inside the group, whose action is just `\mathcal`. If the argument is a single token, just apply `\mathcal` to it.

It's quite easy with `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{m}
 {
  \szumilo_foo:n { #1 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \szumilo_foo:n
 {
  \tl_if_single:nTF { #1 }
   { \mathcal{#1} }
   { \szumilo_foo_multiple:n { #1 } }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \szumilo_foo_multiple:n
 {
  \group_begin:
  \char_set_mathcode:nn { `* } { "8000 }
  #1
  \group_end:
 }
\char_set_active_eq:NN * \mathcal

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\foo{*X}+\foo{X}+\foo{X^A}+\foo{*X^A_B}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you insist on using `#` it's a bit more difficult.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{m}
 {
  \szumilo_foo:n { #1 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \szumilo_foo:n
 {
  \tl_if_single:nTF { #1 }
   { \mathcal{#1} }
   { \szumilo_foo_multiple:n { #1 } }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \szumilo_foo_multiple:n
 {
  \group_begin:
  \tl_set_rescan:Nnn \l_szumilo_foo_arg_tl { \char_set_catcode:nn { `\# } { 12 } } { #1 }
  \char_set_mathcode:nn { `\# } { "8000 }
  \tl_use:N \l_szumilo_foo_arg_tl
  \group_end:
 }
\cs_new:Nn \szumilo_foo_mathcal:NN { \mathcal{#2} }
\char_set_active_eq:nN { `\# } \szumilo_foo_mathcal:NN

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\foo{#X}+\foo{X}+\foo{X^A}+\foo{#X^A_B}$

\end{document}
```

Besides the need of rescanning the argument for making `#` of category 12, we need to swallow one `#` (because these tokens get doubled when they have category 6).

Comment: This looks exactly like what I wanted. I used `#` only as an example so this is not a big deal. Could I choose other symbols in the place of `*` without making it more complicated? Or maybe I should ask: what are the symbols that I cannot use without modifying this approach?

Comment: @KarolSzumiło You can use all characters that are neither letters nor special characters (``* + - ? ! ; : , . ` @``) but not `'`. Of course the selected marker must not appear in other roles in the argument. I added also the trick for using `#`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way, using `listofitems` parsing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\newcommand\foo[1]{\fooaux#1\fooend}
\def\fooaux#1#2\fooend{
  \ifx\relax#2\relax\mathcal{#1}\else
    \setsepchar{"}
    \readlist\mylist{#1#2}
    \foreachitem\i\in\mylist{
      \ifnum\icnt=1\else\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\mathcal\expandafter\fi
      \i
    }
  \fi
}
\begin{document}
$\foo{X}\quad\foo{"X}\quad\foo{X^A}$

$\foo{"X}+\foo{X}+\foo{X^A}+\foo{"X^A_B}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

And an even simpler way with `\catcode`s, producing the same result.

```
\documentclass{article}
\catcode`"=\active %
\def"{\mathcal}
\newcommand\foo{\catcode`"=\active\fooz}
\newcommand\fooz[1]{\foozz#1\fooend}
\def\foozz#1#2\fooend{\ifx\relax#2\relax\mathcal{#1}\else#1#2\fi}
\catcode`"=12 %
\begin{document}
$\foo{X}\quad\foo{"X}\quad\foo{X^A}$

$\foo{"X}+\foo{X}+\foo{X^A}+\foo{"X^A_B}$
\end{document}
```

Since the OP wasn't tied to a particular syntax, I changed the special character from `#` to `"`.